# CygWin installation not completing

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to install `cygwin` on my windows machine. It has passed nearly 5 hours.But installation not competed. Installation progress shows values exceed 100%. Is this the behavior of this or is this an error?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried another mirror?

Comment: Are you trying to install everything? That's a Bad Idea™. Only install the packages you need.